# Change current sound output from terminal

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, headphones

I am trying change output from my hdmi port to headphones and vice versa.
So far I tried with:

```
pactl list sinks | egrep -A2 "Port|Sink"
```

That gets me:

```
   Sink #0
    State: RUNNING
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-surround
--
    Ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority: 5900, available)
    Active Port: hdmi-output-0
    Formats:
        pcm
--
Sink #2
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
--
    Ports:
        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority: 9900, not available)
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority: 9000, available)
    Active Port: analog-output-headphones
    Formats:
        pcm
```

and in order to switch to headphones, I execute :

`pactl set-sink-port 2 analog-output-headphones`

The command is executed but nothing happens. Any ideas ?

( I am currently on my ZorinOS distro )

Comment: Perhaps, sink #2 has no input then is suspended. Use pavucontrol to set sound input to analog output headphone, then you can to it.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka I used pavucontrol, and now the state is suspended. still not working tho!

Comment: Do you see pavucntrol tab: Output Devices volumes for HDMI and Analog headphone? When I play an internet radio via Audacious output set to USB DAC by its software setting and play youtube video on Firefox. There is no switch, just radio is playing through to a USB DAC and youtube audio is playing through a headphone. But I can switch headphones to lineout by pactl set-sink-port x analog-output-lineout. Now nothing from headphones and lineout speaker is playing youtube. Can it be a hint for you?

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka hmm, i am trying to follow. I tried from different apps to set port but sound is still playing from hdmi. I don't understand :(

Comment: This site explains it smarter. https://kodi.wiki/view/PulseAudio

Comment: I do understand what you don't understand, me either. Wish it were like a concert PA and had multiple automatic plug-and-play line-in(s) and a console panel easy-to-operate which audio stream to mix and send output devices.  Someday.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka I will check it out! thanks for elaborating with me